# Are there any data-base design patterns for auditing persisted objects?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, logging, entities

I wonder if there are any data-base design patterns for auditing persisted objects in terms of any CRUD operations on them?

So that I can use that db design

- to see when an object is created
- when and HOW it was Updated in the past including all its properties that may be other entities
- when it was deleted and by whom etc.

**If I sum up**: Are there any db design patterns accepted by the programming community that covers auditing all CRUD operations on persisted entities?

(I would be glad if you can point me to any resource covering this topic).

Answer (score 2):

pencilCake, you usually have two options: save all revisions in one table and mark last revision somehow, or have a separate table (for example, with _AUDIT suffix) to save historical versions. And you have several options how to fill these tables, for example using triggers or in your code, for example using aspects (in java golossary) for CRUD operations. I suggest you to choose one of the libraries for your programming language.